# get current url with "csp intersystem cache objescript"

Tags: intersystems-cache, objectscript

as I can get the current url with csp cache language ? 
without using mv.

I also want to get the current domain
ie if I have this url www.midominio.hn / assets / hola.csp

get www.midominio.hn

Comment: I've solved it in the following way: %request.GetCgiEnv("SERVER_NAME")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved it in the following way: %request.GetCgiEnv("SERVER_NAME")